# R keep rows with maximum value of one column when multiple rows have values close to each other in an other column

Tags: r

I have a data frame with dates and magnitudes. For every case where the dates are within 0.6 years from each other, I want to keep the date with the highest absolute magnitude and discard the other.

- This includes cases where multiple dates are all within 0.6 years from each other. Like `c(2014.2, 2014.4, 2014.5)` which should give `c(2014.4) if that year had the highest absolute magnitude.
- For cases where multiple years could be chained using this criterion (like `c(2016.3, 2016.7, 2017.2)`, where 2016.3 and 2017.2 are not within 0.6 years from each other), I want to treat the dates that are closest to one another as a pair and consider the extra date in the criterion as a next candidate for another pair, (so the output will read like this `c(2016.3,` <s>2016.7</s>, `2017.2)` if 2016.3 had the highest absolute magnitude).

data:

```
set.seed(1)
library(dplyr)
mydf <- data.frame(date = c(2014.25, 2014.41, 2014.53, 2016.3, 
                            2016.7,2017.2,2018.5, 2019.35, 2019.8),
                   magnitude = round(rnorm(9, mean=0, sd=0.4),4))
mydf <- mydf %>% mutate(absmag = abs(magnitude))
mydf
> mydf
     date magnitude absmag
1 2014.25   -0.1222 0.1222
2 2014.41    0.6047 0.6047
3 2014.53    0.1559 0.1559
4 2016.30   -0.2485 0.2485
5 2016.70   -0.8859 0.8859
6 2017.20    0.4500 0.4500
7 2018.50   -0.0180 0.0180
8 2019.35   -0.0065 0.0065
9 2019.80    0.3775 0.3775
```

Desired output:

```
     date magnitude absmag
1 2014.41    0.6047 0.6047
2 2016.70   -0.8859 0.8859
3 2017.20    0.4500 0.4500
4 2018.50   -0.0180 0.0180
5 2019.80    0.3775 0.3775
```

The things I tried so far failed to incoropate the requirements in the bullet points.

This solution can only handle pairs of two items within 0.6 years from each other:

```
whichAreClose <- function(your.number, x, threshold = 0.6){
  x[which(abs(x - your.number) != 0 & abs(x - your.number) < thresh)]}
out1 <- sapply(mydf$date, 
                FUN = whichAreClose, 
                x = mydf$date) %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  split(., cut(seq_along(.), 2, labels = FALSE)) %>% 
  lapply(
    ., function(i){
      mydf %>% 
        filter(date %in% i) %>% 
        slice_min(absmag)}) %>% 
  bind_rows(.) %>% 
  anti_join(mydf, .)

> out1
     date magnitude absmag
1 2014.41    0.6047 0.6047
2 2014.53    0.1559 0.1559
3 2016.30   -0.2485 0.2485
4 2016.70   -0.8859 0.8859
5 2017.20    0.4500 0.4500
6 2018.50   -0.0180 0.0180
7 2019.80    0.3775 0.3775
```

and this solution cannot distinguish different pairs at all:

```
out2 <- mydf %>% 
  mutate(prevdist = abs(date - lag(date)),
         nextdist = abs(date - lead(date)),
         ispair = case_when(prevdist < 0.6 ~ 'yes',
                            nextdist < 0.6 ~ 'yes',
                            TRUE ~ 'no')) %>% 
  filter(ispair == 'yes') %>% 
  slice_min(absmag) %>% 
  anti_join(mydf, .)

> out2
     date magnitude absmag
1 2014.25   -0.5883 0.5883
2 2014.41   -0.1913 0.1913
3 2014.53    0.1672 0.1672
4 2016.30    0.5435 0.5435
5 2017.20    0.1551 0.1551
6 2018.50   -0.0215 0.0215
7 2019.35   -0.5508 0.5508
8 2019.80   -0.1660 0.1660
```

P.S.: feel free to edit the title. I struggled to come up with a good one myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to perform [complete clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete-linkage_clustering) on dates by using `hclust`. The manhattan (i.e. absolute) distances are calculated between pairs of dates. The "complete" clustering method will ensure that every member of a cluster cut at `h` height will be distant at most `h` from the other members.

```r
mydf |>
  mutate(k = {
    dist(date, method = "manhattan") |>
      hclust(method = "complete") |>
      cutree(h = .6)
  })

#>     date magnitude absmag k
#>1 2014.25   -0.2506 0.2506 1
#>2 2014.41    0.0735 0.0735 1
#>3 2014.53   -0.3343 0.3343 1
#>4 2016.30    0.6381 0.6381 2
#>5 2016.70    0.1318 0.1318 2
#>6 2017.20   -0.3282 0.3282 3
#>7 2018.50    0.1950 0.1950 4
#>8 2019.35    0.2953 0.2953 5
#>9 2019.80    0.2303 0.2303 5
```

Here is shown the dendrogram obtained:

[image: dendrogram]

```r
mydf |>
  mutate(k = {
    dist(date, method = "manhattan") |>
      hclust(method = "complete") |>
      cutree(h = .6)
  }) |>
  group_by(k) |>
  filter(absmag == max(absmag)) |>
  as.data.frame()

#>      date magnitude absmag k
#> 1 2014.53   -0.3343 0.3343 1
#> 2 2016.30    0.6381 0.6381 2
#> 3 2017.20   -0.3282 0.3282 3
#> 4 2018.50    0.1950 0.1950 4
#> 5 2019.35    0.2953 0.2953 5
```

Comment: Beautiful! Maybe it would be nice for the sake of completeness to explain in the answer that `dist(. , method = 'manhattan')` enables distance calculations on absolute values and `hclust` is hierarchical clustering. I had to look these up.

Comment: @saQuist Actually, the "manhattan" distance specification wasn't really needed as it is equivalent to "euclidean" distance for univariate clustering. I will expand the explanation nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

With `cumsum` and `purrr::accumulate`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mydf %>% 
  group_by(cum = cumsum(accumulate(c(0, diff(date)), ~ifelse(.x + .y <= 0.6, .x + .y, 0)) == 0)) %>% 
  slice_max(absmag)

     date magnitude absmag    cum
1 2014.53   -0.3343 0.3343      1
2 2016.30    0.6381 0.6381      2
3 2017.20   -0.3282 0.3282      3
4 2018.50    0.1950 0.1950      4
5 2019.35    0.2953 0.2953      5
```

---

**Explanation**:

`purrr:accumulate` takes the difference between the values of the vectors as input, and if the cumulative sum (`.x + .y`) is below 0.6, it outputs the cumulative sum (for instance for the first three elements), but if it's higher than 0.6, the cumsum resets to 0. So for the fourth element, because `0.28 + 1.77 > 0.6`, the function sets the fourth element to `0`.

```r
c(0, diff(mydf$date))
# [1] 0.00 0.16 0.12 1.77 0.40 0.50 1.30 0.85 0.45

accumulate(c(0, diff(mydf$date)), ~ifelse(.x + .y <= 0.6, .x + .y, 0))
# [1] 0.00 0.16 0.28 0.00 0.40 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.45
```

Everytime the cumsum resets to 0, it is actually a new group with subsequent rows being below the thresholds. So, to capture groups, one can use `cumsum(... == 0)`:

```r
cumsum(accumulate(c(0, diff(mydf$date)), ~ifelse(.x + .y <= 0.6, .x + .y, 0)) == 0)
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 3 4 5 5
```

Comment: I got `x object 'd' not found` did you mean `date` there?

Comment: My bad, I meant `c(0, diff(date)`. Forgot to change the name from my attempts.

Comment: It works now. But I find it difficult to grasp what is going on. Could you expand on that?

Comment: Thanks for the explaination. I think in this case, I probably want `slice_max(absmag)` at the end.